# How to test/flash many modules?

Tags: connector, soldering, wiring, test-equipment

Suppose I have several hundred pieces of the same module to test and flash, and the connectors themselves have wire holes in them like below. What's a good way to make the connection without soldering?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pogo pins and a custom test jig. Sparkfun has a tutorial on how they do it for their modules, I recommend doing something similar.